# How do I handle URL variables in Parse.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, parse-platform

I generally access my Parse app by going to `www.mysite.com`.

However, I want to be able to do something like `www.mysite.com/code` or `www.mysite.com?page=code`, and for this to show a specific view within the app, without having to click through.  In other words, I want to detect that a GET variable is present, and use it to determine which view to show.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Backbone's Router](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router). There's [an example in the Anypic.org source code](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/blob/master/Anypic-web/js/anypic.js) you can use.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
  "pic/:object_id": "getPic",
  "*actions": "defaultRoute"
},

getPic: function(object_id) {
  App.showLandingPage();

  var query = new Parse.Query(Photo);
  query.include("user");
  query.get(object_id, {
    success: function(photo) {
      App.landingPageView.showPhoto(photo);
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
      console.error(error);
      // The object was not retrieved successfully.
      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
      App.landingPageView.showError();
    }
  });
},

defaultRoute: function(actions) {
  App.showHomePage();
}
```

});

In this example, navigating to https://anypic.org/pic/XXXXX will call getPic and pass along the value of XXXXX to the getPic function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much familiarity with parse.com, but if you just want to access GET variables within javascript, it's not terribly difficult:

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/